# How do I undo preventDefault(); on touchmove?

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

```
if ((body).hasClass('dialog-visible')){
  document.body.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); 
  }, false);
}
```

I am trying to remove preventDefault(); when the dialog is closed.

Comment: why don't you put a condition on it?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Remove one line of code or ???

Comment: Good question. Android's support for touchmove may be poorly. Without the preventDefault() it's not able to catch long sequences. However say I switch to another site via Ajax and I want to re-enable the default behaviour - what to do?

Answer (score 2):

There is no 'opposite' of preventDefault(); However, you can choose nót to call it at any given time you want, by moving the if:

```
  document.body.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e) {
  if((body).hasClass('dialog-visible')){
       e.preventDefault(); 
  }   
  }, false);
```

Of course, another option is to use `document.body.removeEventListener(function, false)`, but this means you will have to declare your function somewhere.